# Detect If Function Runs on Another Component in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I need to detect if `handleSelectProduct` is being called in another component.
My problem is that if I want the child component(ProductDetailsComponent) to rerender, it still outputs the `console.log('HELO')`. I only want to output the `console.log('HELO')` IF `handleSelectProduct` is being click only.

```
const ProductComponent = () => {
  const [triggered, setTriggered] = React.useState(0);

  const handleSelectProduct = (event) => {
    setTriggered(c => c + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Parent
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSelectProduct}>
        Trigger?
      </button>
      <ProductDetailsComponent triggered={triggered} />
    </div>
  );
};

const ProductDetailsComponent = ({ triggered }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (triggered) {
      console.log('HELO');
    }
  }, [triggered]);

  return <div>Child</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ProductComponent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Do you want the console.log to run everytime handleSelectProduct is clicked? Problem is you have a truthy value (a number) which will always evaluate to true on every render, whether you clicked or not (except when it is 0) so you need to compare old and new values of triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution sounds to me by using an `useRef` to keep the old value, thus consider the `console.log` only when the triggered value changes.

```
const ProductDetailsComponent = ({ triggered }) => {
  const oldTriggerRef = React.useRef(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (triggered !== oldTriggerRef.current) {
      oldTriggerRef.current = triggered;
      console.log('HELO');
    }
  }, [triggered]);

  return <div>Child</div>;
};
```

Comment: If `triggered` is a dynamic value. So `React.useRef(0);` is not always 0

Comment: @Joseph could you elaborate your comment? I can't see the sense of it.